# Is it possible to prevent being ambushed by a FOE?

Tags: etrian-odyssey

FOEs, unlike regular encounters, appear on the map. They always face a direction, and if you walk into them from behind, you always get a preemptive strike. Conversely, if they want into you from behind, they ambush you.

Except every once in a while when I walk head-on into a FOE, I still get ambushed. I can't tell if this is purely random chance or if the battle-start algorithm is getting confused in very specific circumstances. I've played later EO games and have no recollection of ever running into this. I also don't think I've ever gotten a lucky preemptive strike in the same way, but those seem to be a lot rarer than ambushes even with random encounters (I'm not using any passive skills that affect ambushes/preemptive strikes).

Is this just purely random chance, the same way with regular encounters, or is there some specific way I should move into FOEs to avoid this?

I'm playing the Origin collection version, if that matters.